# Characterization of Block Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

The exercise is given as it follows:

If $G$ is connected with order at least $3$, then $G$ is a block iff for all edge $e \in E(G)$ and for each $\{u,v\} \in V(G)$ exists a walk $W$ such that it does not contain $e$.

Prooving that if $G$ is a block $\implies [...]$ it's not so difficult following that if $G$ is a block then exist a cycle such that $\{u,v\}$ is contained within. But I'm stuck prooving that for all edge [...] $\implies G$ is a block. Any hints?

Comment: The converse is not true. Consider the [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph).

Comment: The butterfly is not a block

Comment: Exactly. But it satisfies the condition that for every edge and every pair of vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, there exists a walk in $G$ not containing $e$. So it's  counterexample (to the converse)